# Internet Explorer Security‏

Tags: internet-explorer

I've been googling all day trying to find the right solution for this. I've found bit and pieces but I haven't had any luck.  I need the ability to change the security properties in the security tab of Internet Explorer with either a .bat, .reg or some other type of exe that will change them for me.  I've got over 100 computer that need all the same settings and this would save me a lot of time.

Comment: Did you have an particular settings in mind?  Adding systems to the zones is a bit different from modifying the zone settings.

Comment: If all systems require the same settings you should use Group Policies to set them.

Answer (score 3):

This might help you.  It's an explanation of the security zones and where the settings are stored in the registry.

[**Internet Explorer security zones registry entries for advanced users**](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/182569)